# Is using Xpath necessary when automating Sitecore testing with Webdriver

Tags: .net, selenium, xpath, webdriver, sitecore

I'm currently building out an automated testing framework for Sitecore. Currently I'm using Xpath to locate most of the elements because Sitecore generates IDs dynamically every time you load the page. This can get very tedious. Is there a better way to do this? Should I be using Xpath?

Thanks!

Comment: Personally, I use xpath locators as a last resort. More often than not I can achieve what I want using Css - I prefer the look of css when reading back over old code. If you can't use locators such as link-text, tagname, class name or similar and xpath is the 'easiest' way, if it works, it ain't stupid.

Comment: Have you tried anything else? How did that work out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Not only Sitecore but also other sites or web applications where you
  find Web-elements(DOM level) changes dynamically, then you cannot
  really depend on one or specific Element Locater type for identifying
  them uniquely.
- You have to select the Locater type very wisely. Because some times
  you may find class-name or its Link text more suitable then its Xpath
  or CSS.
- Also where not a single locater is useful to identify our
  web-element, you can go for [Sikuli](http://doc.sikuli.org/tutorials/index.html), [AutoIT](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/autoit-selenium-webdriver/) or any other
  Tool which can be used for Web object identification. Such objects
  you can mostly found in Web-sites with flash contents.
- Answering with the most efficient method is quite difficult but the
  *Xpath* and *CSS* are the one which you can really rely on the most.